# Exception threw in IntegrationTest: RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR no such key

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, reactive-programming, spring-session, spring-webflux

Currently I am trying to convert [microservice sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-microservice-sample) to Spring 5 reactive stack, but when create a simple auth service with Redis(store sessions via Spring Data Redis) and Cassandra(user data via Spring Data Cassandra).

The complete source of the new reactive stack is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-microservice-sample) (WIP).

[AuthServiceApplicationTests](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-microservice-sample/blob/master/auth-service/src/test/java/com/example/authservice/AuthServiceApplicationTests.java) works well when ran Spring Boot Test in a Mock env.

But [IntegrationTests](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-microservice-sample/blob/master/auth-service/src/test/java/com/example/authservice/IntegrationTests.java) failed with exceptions when ran `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`.

The exception info looks:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR no such key
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceReactiveRedisConnection.lambda$translateException$0(LettuceReactiveRedisConnection.java:267) ~[spring-data-redis-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorMap$23(Flux.java:5170) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:243) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$State.onError(RedisPublisher.java:655) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$RedisSubscription.onError(RedisPublisher.java:313) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$SubscriptionCommand.onError(RedisPublisher.java:767) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$SubscriptionCommand.complete(RedisPublisher.java:703) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:558) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:511) ~[lettuce-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) ~[netty-transport-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138) ~[netty-common-4.1.17.Final.jar:4.1.17.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR no such key
... 26 common frames omitted
```

I used the similar solutions to taste new reactive features in Spring Session 2 and Spring Security 5 in [this simple sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/session-header), it worked. The difference is in this sample I used `MapReactiveWebSessionRepository` instead of the redis specific ReactiveWebSessionRepository.

**Updated**, updated Spring Session to 2.0.0.RELEASE in my codes, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Spring Session's `ReactiveRedisOperationsSessionRepository`. I filed a ticket, [issue #954](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/954) to track the further progress.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is a bug in Spring Session's `ReactiveRedisOperationsSessionRepository` (that affects the `2.0.0.RC2` milestone release) and is caused by improper handling of changing the session id.

As of time of writing this comment, the issue has been fixed in the `master` and will be available with upcoming Spring Session `2.0.0.RELEASE` which is [scheduled for January 9th](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/milestones) at the moment.

As a temporary workaround until the `2.0.0.RELEASE` is out, you could avoid using `WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository` as a security context repository in you reactive security configuration, and have Spring Security default to `NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository`.